# Miscrosoft Edge textarea not firing input event when deleting single newline character

Tags: microsoft-edge

When you a have a textarea containing single character `'\n'` the textarea won't fire an input event upon deleting that character. In my case where I want to update a counter with number of remaining characters this behavior causes the counter to display wrong information.

Live demo https://jsfiddle.net/k594e6rt/5/

html:

```
<label>Go into this textarea to the last row and press backspace. It won't trigger the input event despite deleting a char. This demonstrates a bug in the Edge browser.</label><br/>
<textarea id="bug" rows="3"></textarea><br/>
<label>Log:</label><br/>
<div id="log">---<br/></div>
```

js:

```
/* setup */
var bug = document.getElementById('bug');
var problematicText = String.fromCodePoint(10); //newline
bug.value = problematicText

/* debugging setup */
var counter = 1;
var log = document.getElementById('log');

var logEvent = function logEvent(){
    log.innerHTML += (counter++ + ': input fired! <br/>');
}

bug.addEventListener('input', logEvent)
```

**Edit:** Edge version: 13.10586. 
So the issue might have been already fixed in recent version.

**Edit 2:** It's fixed in Edge 14.14393.

Comment: Your jsfiddle worked with my edge browser. No problem there.

Comment: Maybe this idea helps, listen for keyup or change instead of input.
Seems its not perfect yet, http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event
Also maybe u can find here the issue:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed in Edge 14.14393.

Answer (score 0):

```
bug.addEventListener('keyup', logEvent)
```

`keyup` instead of `input` worked fine in my version of edge. And I suppose it should work in every browser. Except stuff like right click paste. So its still not solving all your problems.
https://jsfiddle.net/cjztogvh/

For reference, EDGE version I have is 38.14393.0.0